# What's the best way to access Session Data in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, session, spring-data-redis, spring-session

What's the best way to access Session Data in Spring Boot?

I'm developing a new microservice that included login/logout/2fa operation.
Login will consist 3 or 4 steps, like -> /validateUser (1.Step), /validateOneTimePassword (2.Step) ... and more some paths/steps.

We want to manage the session in Redis(distributed) and I added the needed conf/depend. When I make a request I can see creating a new session in Redis.

When I searched for the best way, I found some approaches.
Such as:

1:

```
@PostMapping("/myrequest")
public void handleMyRequest(HttpSession session, @RequestBody RequestObject requestObject) {
   session.getAttribute("myKey"); 
   ...
}
```

2:

```
@PostMapping("/myrequest")
public void handleMyRequest(@RequestBody RequestObject requestObject) {

   ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
   HttpSession session = attr.getRequest().getSession();
   session.getAttribute("myKey"); 
   ...
}
```

3:

```
@Autowired
HttpSession httpSession;

@PostMapping("/myrequest")
public void handleMyRequest(@RequestBody RequestObject requestObject) {
   session.getAttribute("myKey"); 
   ...
}
```

Which one of these? Let's say we decided on the right thing so now I have a new question.

Using session should we pass the session parameter to the session layer? Or where do need we to make set/get session operation? Controller layer, service layer which one?

Please explain that.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the 3 ways are fine but 1 and 3 will give you clean code. If multiple methods are accessing the session then number 3 would be the best.

As far as the other question is concerned, it all depends on use case. If you just need to read the values, you can extract the values in controller layer and pass it to the service layer, increasing chances of reusing the service layer code. If you need to set something in session and need to be done at the middle of business logic, you may have to send it to service layer.